# How to debug dynamically loadable plugins with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, plugins

i am struggling with how you could run and debug a product that has dynamic loadable plugin dlls. we currently have a solution that contains a wpf application that runs by a debug configuration. when the application starts it will scan for and load plugin dlls that are placed beside the application. the plugin project is placed in the same solution.

i don't really want to create a project reference from the application to the plugin because i want to be able to publish the plugin and the application separately...

in the past we set a build directory on all the projects to use a common directory. that caused the dll was beside the application when we debugged. so it was loaded and used. but a common build directory caused other issues and we were not able to debug the application without the plugin easily anymore.

my idea was to solve it somehow through run configurations. one configuration to run the base application only. and another where the plugins that should be loaded in addition or something similar.

has anyone experienced similar use cases? is there another idea of what we could try to debug an application with plugins and without plugins?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What if you will try to configure output for the plugins to the bin\Debug of main project? I think if near to dll will be pdb file.. VisualStudio will recognize the project in your solution. If no - you always can use System.Diagnostic.Debugger.Attach() for explicitly load debugger.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You load the necessary and very specific plugins to reproduce a specific environment. If you want to inspect it verify the functionality of  the plugin alone you should write unit tests. Why can't you debug your application without plugins? Aside from your very broad and unclear question, it is impossible to answer such a design or architecture related question without knowing your existing system. Normally an application should be able to execute without possible plugins what leads to the assumption that your architecture or application design is special.

Comment: i try to make it clearer:
we have a so solution that contains a wpf project, that can execute on its own. so i can just launch a run configuration and debug it.

in the same solution there is also another project that adds some functionality only if the dll is beside the executeable... so if i just set the same output path starting the debug launch will always start with the additional functionality...
if i dont set any output path i cant see any way how i could start from the IDE with the additional functionality